# Wordpress: update_post_meta not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am modifying an existing plugin and I want to add a new field to the form and then have that field be submitted along with the post. The post gets submitted to wp_posts. I have read on Google that to do this one simply needs to use `update_post_meta`. I am trying to insert data into a new column I made in PHPMyAdmin. I named the column `post_amount`. The field name is `amount_field`. Although I'm a beginner, something about "just use `update_post_meta`" that I've read seems too simple to be all that I need. But I might be wrong. Maybe I'm using it wrong?

**Note** - this whole attempt is due to me wanting to create a new column in the wp_posts table and add data to it with each posts. Is this even the correct way to do this? I see the words "meta_key" and "meta_value" and it makes me think that this will actually end up adding data in the wp_postmeta table....or is that the intended destination?

```
$question_array = array(
            'post_title'        =>  $fields['title'],
            'post_author'       =>  $user_id,
            'post_content'      =>  apply_filters('ap_form_contents_filter', $fields['description']),
            'post_type'         =>  'question',
            'post_status'       =>  $status,
            'comment_status'    =>  'open',
        );

        if(isset($fields['parent_id']))
            $question_array['post_parent'] = (int)$fields['parent_id'];

        $question_array = apply_filters('ap_pre_insert_question', $question_array );

        $post_id = wp_insert_post($question_array);

        $post_amount = $fields['amount_field']; //My code

        update_post_meta($post_id, 'post_amount', $post_amount); //My code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made a mistake updating your `post_id`.

In `update_post_meta($post_id, 'post_amount', $post_amount);`

you don't have **ID** of the post or the **ID** you want to update.
**$post_id** parameter is declared to Insert Post in your above code.
`$post_id = wp_insert_post($question_array);` So, update post query didn't find the ID.

You need **ID** to update post meta. It didn't find any id so it didn't update `meta_key`. SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH.

Try using `add_post_meta` instead of `update_post_meta`.

See the [Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)

Comment: Wait I'm confused. I thought that when you use `$post_id = wp_insert_post($question_array)`, if the insertion is successful then `wp_insert_post` returns the ID of the post. Therefore, it gets stored in `$post_id`. I saw that in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191254/wordpress-update-post-meta-and-get-post-meta. Are you saying that my post isn't getting inserted successfully? Because I am looking in PHPMyAdmin and I see it appear there.

Comment: yes, you are right. Try `add_post_meta` instead of `update_post_meta`. What I meant was, `update_post_meta` works when there's an existing `ID` of the post. Sometimes the new meta don't get updated using `update_post_meta`. It should work if you use `add_post_meta`.

Comment: It still doesn't work. [Take a look at this image](http://imgur.com/HNzOF7s) - the column is still not getting filled with data. What might be causing this? What should I check for?

Comment: This is supposed to go to `wp_posts` table correct?

Comment: WAAAIIIT I see now! This is filling in data into `wp_postmeta` table. [See image](http://imgur.com/dlAbNxc). So is this the only way people add new data to a table? It seems kind of strange that I can't just make a new column and add data to it with every post.

Comment: `wp_update_postmeta` or `up_insert_postmeta` inserts or updates value to `wp_postmeta` table. Yes, you can make a new column but you need custom query for that. see the reference [https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows]